# Make a button clickable only after a date

Tags: java, android-studio, datetime, button, onclick

I would like to know what should I put in the OnClick of a button to make it clickable let's say between 1 PM and 5 PM, but the rest of the time it'll just display a toast saying "Available at 1 PM only." ?

Or what method should I use to save/check the time?

Here is my button for now :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void OnClick(View v){

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote. I do not see the problem with this clear specific Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;

if
( 
    ( ! lt.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) )   // If 1 PM or later ( in other words, if not before 1 PM )
    &&                                          // …and…
    lt.isBefore( LocalTime.of( 17 , 0 )         // if not yet 5 PM
) 
{
    … proceed 
}
else
{
    … reject user
}
```

## Half-Open

The [Answer by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60792038/642706) is close, wisely making use of the modern *java.time* classes. However, in date-time work, it is usually best to define spans of time using the Half-Open approach. In this approach, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So the range of 1 PM to 5 PM starts at 13:00 and runs up to, but does not include, 17:00.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) ;
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 17 , 0 ) ;
```

Capture the current time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or specify a zone such as `Africa/Tunis` or `Asia/Tokyo`. 
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( z ) ;
```

Compare to the start and stop range. We use the `equals`, [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore(java.time.LocalTime)), and `isAfter` methods on [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) to compare.

Tip: A short way to ask "is equal to or later than" is "is not before".

```
boolean nowInEffect = ( ! now.isBefore( start ) ) && ( now.isBefore( stop ) ) ;
```

Then take your user-interface action.

```
if ( nowInEffect ) {
    … proceed
} else {
    … tell user to check back later
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: May I ask why you spent time writing such a large answer for a -3 voted question that is already solved and basic knowledge.

Comment: @Nand Because (a) I don't care about the votes on the question, a bad question with a good answer can still help others. And (b) I don't recall any similar time-of-day range questions having been asked, so it is worthwhile. I'm not sure this Question actually deserves its 3 down-votes. And (c) I would certainly not say that date-time handling is in the "basic knowledge" of most programmers. The subject is surprisingly tricky and complicated. For example: the issue of time zone in determining the time-of-day that I covered is not obvious to many folks.

Comment: @Nand And (d) other answers on this page are suggesting using the terrible date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar` that are now legacy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void OnClick(View v){
                LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
                // simply check the hour of the day
                if (time.getHour() >= 13 && time.getHour() < 17) {
                   // Welcome for business.
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Available at 1PM only.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Note the use of [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) which is the preferred method for time.  There is also [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) if the need arises.

You may also want to consider setting a timer to enable and disable the button at appropriate times.  You could have the button's title say "Closed" or "Open" depending on the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Date method that is avaible in basic java library.
Something like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm") ;
dateFormat.format(date);

if(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).after(dateFormat.parse("13:00")) && dateFormat.format(date)).before(dateFormat.parse("17:00")));
{
    System.out.println("Accepted");
}else{
    System.out.println("Only avaible at 1PM only");
}
```

Put this in your onClick function.

If this help you please vote me up. I’am here new and want to have some basic reputation. Thanks!

Comment: this is the old java date api. I would suggest you post a solution with the "new" (java 8) api.